# get total number of records retrieved with pagination in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

I wanna show the total number of records of the query. The problem is that I'm using paginator, so.. only show me the number of record of the page, and I need the number of all the records.

This is my code:

```
 public function index()
{
    $paisFK = $this -> Auth -> User()['paisFK'];

    $this->paginate['contain'] = ['Ciudades'];
    $this->paginate['conditions'] = ['Ciudades.paisFK' => $paisFK];

    $complejos = $this->paginate($this->Complejos);

    $this->set(compact('complejos'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['complejos']);

    //Obtenemos la cantidad de complejos:

    $number = $complejos->count();
    $this->set('number',$number);
}
```

Someone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paginator component adds pagination details to the request objects params, using the key `paging`, where the data is nested using the alias of the table object.

Check

```
debug($this->request->param('paging'));
```

This data is easily accessible in your view templates via the paginator helpers `param()` method.

```
$this->Paginator->param('count');
```

Also, depending on how you want to use the value, you could also use the `counter()` method with a custom format. It supports various tokens, including `{{count}}`.

```
$this->Paginator->counter('There is a total of {{count}} record(s)...');
```

See also

- **[API > \Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper::param()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.View.Helper.PaginatorHelper.html#_param)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Paginator > Creating a Page Counter](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#creating-a-page-counter)**

Comment: I'm trying  $number = $this->Paginator->param('count');
        $this->set('number',$number); but have a error: "Error: Call to undefined method Cake\Controller\Component\PaginatorComponent::param() "

Comment: @FederickJons Because you're accessing a [**component**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html), in your controller, not a [**helper**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html), in your view template. As mentioned, the `param()` methods belongs to the paginator view helper, ie there's no need to pass any data to the view on your own, it will already be available there automatically.

Answer (score 0):

there is a complete solution, if you follow this, I think solution here:

Controller:

```
public $paginate =[
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => [
        'tble.id' => 'asc'
    ]
];

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
}

public function index()
{
    $product = TableRegistry::get('tble');
    $query = $product->find();
    $this->set(array('data'=>$query));
    $this->set('tble', $this->paginate($query));


    $this->render('index');
}
```

Index.ctp:

```
<?= $this->Paginator->prev('<< Previous') ?>
<?= $this->Paginator->next('Next >>') ?>
<?= $this->Paginator->counter() ?>
```

`tble` Is a example of your DB Table.